# Merging two "lm" objects in one in R

Tags: r, merge, lm

I have two class "lm" objects which came from linear fits; let's recall them as fit1 and fit2

I want to create an unique variable, say "fits" of class object "lm" containing the two objects as elements. 
This is in order to apply functions as "confint" or "summary" on single components of fits.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Just put them in a list and use functions like `lapply` or `map` to apply your functions to the list elements. E.g., `lapply(list(fit1, fit2), confint)`.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `"lmList"` class, which is returned by the `lmList` function from package nlme:

```
fit1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
fit2 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = iris)

fits <- list(fit1, fit2)
class(fits) <- "lmList"

library(nlme)
confint(fits)
#[[1]]
#                2.5 %     97.5 %
#(Intercept)  5.579865 7.47258038
#Sepal.Width -0.529820 0.08309785
#
#[[2]]
#                2.5 %   97.5 %
#(Intercept) 0.9393664 1.227750
#Petal.Width 2.1283752 2.331506
```

See `help("lmList")` for a list of functions with methods for `lmList` objects. (You need to take special care if the fits don't have identical formulas as is the case in the example above.)